# fancyhdr and rightmark - how to remove the dot

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, punctuation

I am using the `fancyhdr` package to create a heading for my document. It is working really good, but on the odd pages on the right side I get "1.1. Section 1", but what I want is "1.1 Section 1". Could you help me with erasing the dot?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} %chapter oben ohne Nummer 
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1} %macht das nich alles Großgeschrieben wird 

\fancyhead{} %löscht den Standardtext oben 
\fancyhead[LE] {\leftmark} %chaptername=current language bezeichnung für Kapitel, \chaptermark= Titel; Text in{} wird links bzw. rechts gestzt (gerade und ungerade Seiten)
\fancyhead[RO] {\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO] {\thepage} %the page returns page number; R=Right O=Odd page L=LEft E=even page
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt} %dicke vom Strich
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % empty pagestyle plan (für Seiten mit Chapter o.ä)
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\blindtext
\section{Section1}
\blindtext
\subsection{subsection1}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add  `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection ~ \ #1}}`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} %chapter oben ohne Nummer 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection ~ \ #1}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1} %macht das nich alles Großgeschrieben wird 

\fancyhead{} %löscht den Standardtext oben 
\fancyhead[LE] {\leftmark} %chaptername=current language bezeichnung für Kapitel, \chaptermark= Titel; Text in{} wird links bzw. rechts gestzt (gerade und ungerade Seiten)
\fancyhead[RO] {\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO] {\thepage} %the page returns page number; R=Right O=Odd page L=LEft E=even page
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt} %dicke vom Strich
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % empty pagestyle plan (für Seiten mit Chapter o.ä)
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter1}
    \blindtext
    \section{Section1}
    \blindtext
    \subsection{subsection1}
    \Blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to keep the entire structure the same, you can patch `\sectionmark` and perform a search-and-replace; add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\sectionmark}% <cmd>
  {\thesection.}% <search>
  {\thesection}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

There already is a space inserted between the section number (`\thesection`) and the section title:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The dot is added in `\sectionmark`, which is defined by

```tex
\def\sectionmark##1{%
  \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
      \thesection. \ %
    \fi
  ##1}}}}
```

in standard classes `report` and `book`, see `texdoc classes`. You can redefine `\sectionmark` to remove the dot as [@SimonDispa's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623939) shows.